# openscad failes to install : broken dependcy libqt5scintilla2-12v5

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

Trying to install opensad from the ubuntu package repository on Kubuntu version 16.04 LTS. The install very quickly fails with the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 openscad : Depends: libqt5scintilla2-12v5 (>= 2.8.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am hoping there's an update that fixes this. As far as I know this has been the case for several months alas.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on https://github.com/openscad/openscad/issues/1792. You need to install several dependencies manually:

- Download two DEB packages from https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/yakkety/universe/base/libqt5scintilla2-l10n and https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/yakkety/universe/base/libqt5scintilla2-12v5
- Install them using `sudo dpkg -i <package>`. First libqtscintilla2-l10n, then 12v5.
- Now you can install openscad using `sudo apt install openscad`.

Happy Hacking!